# Issue with member function declaration in class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmainwindow

I have been battling with an issue on Qt for a while now and figured I'd come by here to see if anyone had any solutions.

I've created a GUI using the QT tools and have programmed all of the functions for each respective thing. However, I can't seem to successfully rectify the following issue:

> C:\Python34\2SprayCoater\mainwindow.cpp:11: error: no 'int
>   mainwindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)' member function declared in class
>   'mainwindow'  mainwindow::MainWindow(QWidget
>   *parent):QMainWindow(parent)

The part of code from the library in question is:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class mainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    explicit mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~mainwindow();
```

And the reference to this code in the cpp file is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "main.cpp"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>



mainwindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent)

{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

I tried to fix this by simply changing explicit

> mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

in the header file to

> explicit mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0):QMainWindow(parent);

Which just ends up creating a slough of different issues, but fixes the original. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you include main.cpp in mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: I found that when I do it any other way I get compiling errors with serial port initialization. Putting it in main and referencing then including main.cpp in mainwindow.cpp fixed this.

Comment: You could share the entire project through github, drive or similar.

Comment: https://github.com/Zacharytm/CoaterGUI

Comment: You should not modify the things that the IDE generates, but you know what it is for.

Comment: I'm fixing things, wait a moment, please.

Comment: The correction of your code is here: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/2SprayCoater

Comment: Thank you for fixing that for me!

Comment: I have posted a response, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is generated because you removed some necessary headers, for example:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

This is generated by the .ui file, ie the design is converted to code before compiling it. The ui attribute needs that file, also ui is a pointer so to access its methods you must use `->`. You must change:

```
ui.setupUi(this);
```

to

```
ui->setupUi(this);
```

Another serious problem is that you have renamed mainwindow to MainWindow in the constructor.

```
explicit mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

mainwindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent)
            [here]
```